# Excel - Reference cells with a variable cell

Tags: excel

I know this might sound crazy, I tried many things to make it work, but I did not. It probably have no solution, but if there is, please help me here.

Excel example:

[image]

Using the example, you can see that Table 1 there are: Robert, Joan, Lea, Ralph, and Doug. Table 2 there are Amanda, Robert, Joan, Maria, and Renan.

Only Robert and Joan are in table 2 from table one and I would like to **import automatically their ID to table 2 without VBA.**

I could use IFS to compare each cell, but it is too much work and also a table is dynamic, can add a new person and it would be out of the range to compare.

I thought then a possibility to count how many members table 1 have, **B20=COUNTA(B4:B10) and remove the "name" and "total" from the answer.**
The number in B20 would be the number of elements in my array.
To find the id, instead of using **IF**, I could use **SUMIF(B5:B9,B14,C5:C9)** (which would give me the id for Robert, for example). Is there a way that I can use the information from B20 to define my ranges: B5:B9 and C5:C9 and make it dynamic?

If it is too confusing, please let me know.

Comment: Why not using `VLOOKUP` ?

Comment: I mean you could, but you wouldn't still get the dynamic array setting that I am looking for.

Comment: This sounds exactly what VLOOKUP or INDEX+MATCH was designed for.  If those do not solve your issue you should specifically explain why.

Comment: Is your data dynamic in table 1? If not than create a name range for your table 1 and use it in `VLOOKUP` function.

Comment: It is dynamic.
I created that table just to exemplify, but I guess I should've done better. What I am doing is a budget for two semesters.
In the middle of a semester a employee could be hired, so the table 1 is dynamic.
When goes to table 2, not necessarily every single employee will go to next semester and we can also hire more employees. So even though the VLOOKUP and INDEX+MATCH can solve just fine, if I insert a data bellow the data range, it will keep the old array and lose data from the new one. The only solution would be adding name and total to my array range.

Comment: I mean it is possible with some COUNT's within an INDIRECT then an INDEX and MATCH but it is seems overly complicated when you could just put the tables aligned horizontally not vertically or possibly on two separate sheets and just reference the whole column for your lookups.  On a side note related to that how are you doing the Total then?  Is that dynamic also?

Comment: That is a great question Chance, I have not though about before the question, because I was using VBA to insert new employees in my old spreadsheet and then when I started a new one I did not want to use VBA. If I do that, it will also lose the reference. Thanks for making me realize that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use vlookup and if condition.

```
=IF((ISNUMBER(VLOOKUP(A11,A3:E8,2,0))),VLOOKUP(A11,A3:E8,2,0),"")
```

[image]

Assuming Id's are numeric only.

Since more employees are going to be added take range as A:E. Hence the formula is :

```
=IF((ISNUMBER(VLOOKUP(A11,A:E,2,0))),VLOOKUP(A11,A:E,2,0),"")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign names to the tables in Formula>Name Manager and then use the VLOOKUPs or Index/Match formulas mentioned in the other answers. Then for the range, just put the name of the table so you don't have to manually change it everytime you add a new name.

J

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and try the INDEX/MATCH combination of formulas in Excel.

```
    =INDEX([column with data you want to print],
     MATCH([value you are looking for],
     [column of values that might have this value],
     [exact match]))
```

I went ahead and tried this on your data set and here's what I got:

```
    =INDEX($B$1:$B$5,MATCH(A8,$A$1:$A$5,0))
```

[image]

If #N/A shows up, that value was not found in the data set.  Otherwise, if its a match, the data will appear.

Comment: Hello Alec, Thank you for your answer, it is helpful to find a different solution in order to find the value. Although I still need to go manually and set the range and that is what I am trying to avoid to do.